# C# Blazor Table RemoveVariant event

Tags: c#, blazor

This is a Razor page.

I'm trying to write a function that can be binded to an event that deletes the current row.

How to write the function?

*the html code*

```
                @for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
                {
                    <th width="250" > @(i + 1)
                        <MatIconButton Icon="clear" OnClick="@RemoveVariant" class="text-right"></MatIconButton>
                
                    </th>
                }
            </tr>
```

*C# code*

```
private void RemoveVariant(int index)
    {
        ShouldRender();
     
        l_VKDTI_TSI.Remove(l_VKDTI_TSI[index]);
        l_VKDTI_VI.Remove(l_VKDTI_VI[index]);
        l_VKDTI_DIMENSIONS.Remove(l_VKDTI_DIMENSIONS[index]);
        l_VKDTI_VW.Remove(l_VKDTI_VW[index]);
        l_VKDTI_ENGINE.Remove(l_VKDTI_ENGINE[index]);
        l_VKDTI_TRANSMISSION.Remove(l_VKDTI_TRANSMISSION[index]);
        l_VKDTI_DRIVETRAIN.Remove(l_VKDTI_DRIVETRAIN[index]);
        l_VKDTI_TAW.Remove(l_VKDTI_TAW[index]);
        l_VKDTI_HUMP.Remove(l_VKDTI_HUMP[index]);
        l_VKDTI_WAP.Remove(l_VKDTI_WAP[index]);
        l_VKDTI_PEDAL.Remove(l_VKDTI_PEDAL[index]);
        l_VKDTI_BOOSTER.Remove(l_VKDTI_BOOSTER[index]);
        l_VKDTI_MC.Remove(l_VKDTI_MC[index]);
        l_VKDTI_FB.Remove(l_VKDTI_FB[index]);
        l_VKDTI_RB.Remove(l_VKDTI_RB[index]);
        l_VKDTI_OVI.Remove(l_VKDTI_OVI[index]);

            
        l_ESPTI_VAF_ALL.Remove(l_ESPTI_VAF_ALL[index]);
        l_ESPTI_VAF_ALL_SELECTED.Remove(l_ESPTI_VAF_ALL_SELECTED[index]);
            

        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your function with a copy of the loop variable.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
{
   var iCopy = i;
   <th width="250" > 
       <MatIconButton Icon="clear" OnClick="@(()=>RemoveVariant(iCopy))" class="text-right"></MatIconButton>                
   </th>
}
```